# Override a UICollectionView function in Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, overriding

I have a vibrate function in my app which I want to be triggered inside every "didHighlight" function of every collectionView in my app.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     softVibrate()
}
```

The question is how I can override this didHighlight delegate function in one place so there would be no need to call it individually for every single collectionViews manually?

I searched for this but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for multiple collectionViews across different classes? If this is the case I would recommend against it. If you want to remove it for one collectionView in the future it will create complications.

Comment: @MatthewMitchell Yes, I want to use it in every collectionView in all classes. Thanks for the warning by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class e.g. VibratedCollectionViewDelegate that conforms NSObject and UICollectionViewDelegate:

```swift
class VibratedCollectionViewDelegate: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate {}
```

and override this method inside your new class.
Then should set in yourViewContoller:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  let collectionView = UICollectionView()
  let vibratedCollectionViewDelegate = VibratedCollectionViewDelegate()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.delegate = vibratedCollectionViewDelegate
    }

}
```

If you need extra overrides of UICollectionViewDelegate methods, you can create a new class that inherited a VibratedCollectionViewDelegate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it now & I had a problems with it,   I have to handle a bunch of unwanted delegate functions from UICollectionViewDelegate when I conform the VibratedCollectionViewDelegate class to UICollectionViewDelegate.

Comment: And finally I got a crash at this line:   collectionView.delegate = vibratedCollectionViewDelegate as! UICollectionViewDelegate

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to inherit NSObject. So, you should declare your VibratedCollectionViewDelegate like `class VibratedCollectionViewDelegate: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate {. }`. I edited my code above. And the second thing: you shouldn't use force unwrap `as!`.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried it as well and this also did not work, seems the collectionView delegate is stopped working...